# Dropdown of existing posts in a metabox

Tags: wordpress, drop-down-menu, custom-fields, meta-boxes

I want to have ability to choose for each page what post should appear in a sidebar, from multiple posts type. So I understand that I need a meta box with a dropdown list of all posts, but I don't know how to build this in functions.

I only [found this solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/custom-field-meta-populated-by-dropdown-of-existing-posts/142644#142644) which is quite similar to what I want, but this doesn't help me to much, because I can only choose from a single post type and display only in post pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free plugin that will solve all of your woes. It's called [ACF or Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). It has the ability to add a list of posts to a field and attach that field to pages. Here's how you'd do it:

First install the plugin and navigate to the custom fields screen. Setup your field exactly like this:

[image: ACF screenshot of posts]

Then in the options below that section you need to select these options:

[image: ACF page options]

That will tell ACF to put the field only on pages. After you have set that up you will get a little sidebar block like this:

[image]

You can then select each post for the page and it will return that object on the frontend. You do need to use a little code to get the frontend to spit out the posts you need. Here is the code to get a frontend option from ACF. Inside of the `sidebar.php` file you need to add this code:

```
global $post; // Get the global post object

$sidebar_posts = get_field('posts', $post->ID); // Get the field using the post ID

foreach($sidebar_posts as $sidebar_post){ // Loop through posts
    echo $sidebar_post->post_title; // Echo the post title
}
```

This will simply loop through the posts you select and echo out the title. You can do more with this by adding some other Wordpress post functions using [`setup_postdata()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata). This will allow you to do things like `the_title()` and `the_content()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is the best yeah yeah! but have an issue with this: when i select posts from dropdown and i upload page in dashboard my selections doesn't save, it goes to default value "- Select -", but this not on all pages. only on some it saves my options on upload but others no, really chaotic and no logic :( what can i do now?

Comment: Usually when the dashboard isn't saving something you either have a javascript error in the admin, or one of your plugins is firing an error on post save. Make sure all of your plugins are up to date and possibly inspect your admin with developer tools to see if there are any errors.